# WPF pass object to datagrid's converter and change color of one cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

currently I am trying to make converter, that changes background color of one cell in DataGrid's row. Each row represents one `CustomTask` object. Now my converter changes backroung of entire row. It's not what I want, I need to change background of only one chosen cell.

My xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="customTasksDataGrid" Margin="10,10,10,38" Grid.Column="1" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo" Binding="{Binding Foo}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bar" Binding="{Binding Bar}"/>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

My converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DataRowView), typeof(Brush))]
public class DateToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        CustomTask t = (CustomTask)value;
        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,0,0,120));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Changing color of entire row roks perfectly now.
How to change for example `Bar` cell background color depending on `Foo` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `TextColumn` style individually, not the entire row.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="customTasksDataGrid" Margin="10,10,10,38" Grid.Column="1" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo" Binding="{Binding Foo}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bar" Binding="{Binding Bar}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying to do so, but I think that I forgot `Binding Path=.` form